After deleting SharePoint 2019 site - Some content databases are growing too large causes content database to show error
Please understand that I am a NEW SharePoint Admin.  I know for a fact that there is plenty of drive space.  I am nowhere near the SP threshold.  I have disabled the rule for now so that I dont have to keep putting the content database back into ready mode each hour.  Are there any tricks anyone can provide me.  I've done all the google searching and I've reached the end of being able to help myself.  SQL server shows no errors.  I'm not sure what I would be looking for in the logs.

The ideal solution for the SharePoint Health Analyzer warning "Some content databases are growing too large" is to move some of the site collections to other smaller content databases or create new content database(s) and move there by using the Move-SPSite PowerShell command.
Note that, just moving the site collection data to another content database will not reduce your content database size. Once the site collection content moved to another content database, the "Gradual Site Delete" timer job will delete the site collection from source content DB but still keep the unused space in source content DB.
Finally, to free the unused space, you or DBA need to shrink the content database by running DBCC SHRINKDATABASE command.
I hope this helps!
